# Login to windows using java

Tags: java, authentication, passwords

I want my program to start before the user logs into the computer. This means that I would like to start my program before the user logs into the computer by entering the password.

In fact my program is one which senses the person in front of the computer and get him logged into the computer using the password which would have already been provided by the user before. For this I would have to put up a screen during the log in process.

Also please help me out about how use the user password to get him logged in.

Comment: It might be possible to run the program as a system level service. You could try taking a look at [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)

Comment: can you please explain a bit how to use it

Comment: Never used it, best bet is to follow the link and read there documention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install your program in such a way that it run as a service on operating system.

Using a third party tool like advanced installed, you could easily do this. Its as simple as a creating a wizard. Check here - http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java-service.html#preparing

Regarding your second goal, you perhaps want to build something like a 'Fingerprint login' which is common on laptop PC now-a-days.

In the same manner, you need to have some way to capture an identifying data of the user. say a face recognition through a webcam. Your service should get input from the webcam and able to identify the person. Then using the logon service of the operating system, it may supply the pre-input password to automatically login into the system.